Why reduce security checks or use `unchecked` to save only a small amount of gas? How significant is the benefit?
I found several different token contracts, some of which add security checks to all operations, while others omit checks for operations that are unlikely to overflow. I would like to know if the gas savings from skipping a security check are significant, or if it's really worth taking the risk of reducing security checks? I would greatly appreciate if someone could answer this for me.☺☺☺
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[recipient] += amount;

This is a token contract in Solidity version 0.8, where security checks have been reduced.
      uint256 checkedSupply = safeAdd(totalSupply, tokens);

      // return money if something goes wrong
      if (tokenCreationCap < checkedSupply) throw;  // odd fractions won't be found

      totalSupply = checkedSupply;
      balances[msg.sender] += tokens;  // safeAdd not needed; bad semantics to use here

This is a token contract in Solidity version 0.4, where security checks have been reduced.
        // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
        // if (_value > _allowance) throw;

        uint fee = (_value.mul(basisPointsRate)).div(10000);
        if (fee > maximumFee) {
            fee = maximumFee;
        }
        if (_allowance < MAX_UINT) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
        }
        uint sendAmount = _value.sub(fee);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(sendAmount);
        if (fee > 0) {
            balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(fee);
            Transfer(_from, owner, fee);
        }


However, there are also some more cautious token contracts that apply security checks to all operations.

As of Solidity 0.8, the compiler has built-in safety checks, especially overflow checks for arithmetic operations (such as addition, subtraction, and multiplication). Therefore, if you manually skip these safety checks (such as using unchecked blocks), you can indeed save some gas. However, whether it is worth skipping these checks depends on the specific situation.
Gas Savings
unchecked blocks: Skipping checks may save a small amount of gas, especially in loops or with a large number of operations. This is mainly because the built-in arithmetic overflow checks introduce some additional EVM instructions.
10 gas: In some simple scenarios, the gas savings may be negligible. You can quantify the gas savings with a gas analysis tool (such as Hardhat or the gas profiler in Foundry). Generally, safety checks may save about 5 to 10 gas units per operation, but the cumulative difference may be noticeable.
Risk vs. Reward
Safety: Solidity 0.8 automatically performs overflow checks, which greatly reduces the risk of security vulnerabilities. If you skip these checks (such as in an unchecked block), you need to be very sure that these operations cannot overflow, otherwise it may cause serious security issues, especially under unexpected input or attack scenarios.
Contract size: Safety checks usually increase the bytecode size a bit, and the larger the bytecode size of the contract, the higher the gas fee when deployed. In very complex contracts, this may become a factor that needs to be weighed.
Real-world use cases: In real applications, operations such as token transfers or balance calculations tend not to cause overflows, so you may be able to use unchecked safely in some cases, but sufficient auditing and testing are still required.
Is it worth skipping the checks?
If the gas savings are critical to the execution efficiency of the contract (such as high-frequency transactions or loop operations), skipping the safety checks may be worth considering, but you must be sure that these operations will never overflow or produce errors. Otherwise, keeping the built-in safety checks is usually a better choice because it provides additional protection against unexpected errors or attacks.
